# For how long will we be able to increase the power of the LHC?

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider

And what can we do to make new discoveries in the fundamental(particle) physics if the LHC doesn't bring results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHC has already reached its maximum power, which was designed to be 14 TeV. It doesn't always run at this power and started out at lower power, but most of the data is now taken near the design maximum of 14 TeV (see for instance https://home.cern/about/engineering/restarting-lhc-why-13-tev).

In order to get more power, you need a new accelerator. There are many designs out there such as the ILC (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Linear_Collider), which is a completely different type of collider.

Aside from new colliders, the question "what else can you do" is too broad, in particular because people now begin to approach problems that are up to now only solved with high energy physics from other areas of physics such as atomic physics (see for instance http://dirac.ups-tlse.fr/fleig/talks/Fleig_Smolenice2014.pdf).

Comment: is it not 2 times 13 Tev ?

Comment: No, the collision energy is 14 TeV as per the linked CERN article. So it's more like 2*7 with 7 TeV each beams energy in the lab frame.